# Writing a pseudocode algorithm for GCSE

Tags: python, computer-science, pseudocode

My text book asks me to "write pseudo code algorithm which inputs 10 numbers. Each time a number less than zero is input, program displays which number it is, and its value. When all numbers have been input, display the average of all the negative numbers. Your algorithm should allow for the fact that there may be no negative numbers".

The issue I have is that I'm unsure on how to write pseudo code correctly, so I've written it in python code-however, that is not necessarily the task. Furthermore, I've been able to more or less to everything but the issue where I need display the average of all the negative numbers has gotten me stuck... I'm not sure how to add that into my code and I am desperate! Need this for school tomorrow!

```
count = 0
nums = []
while count != 10:
    num = int(input ("enter a number "))
    nums.append(num)
    if num < 0:
        print (num)
        neg_nums.append(num)
    count = count+1
print (neg_nums)
```

I actually need to print the average of all the negative numbers, however I have no clue on how I can actually code that into this...

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. Just store only the negative numbers to the list and then in the end sum all of them up and divide by the amount of negative numbers. I also changed the loop from while loop to for loop, because it makes the code clearer and more compact:

```
neg_nums = []
for _ in range(10):
    num = int(input("enter a number "))
    if num < 0:
        print(num)
        neg_nums.append(num)

if neg_nums:
    print(sum(neg_nums) / len(neg_nums))
else:
    print("no negative numbers")
```

We also check in the end if there were some negative numbers inputted, so we don't end up calculating 0 / 0.